# Latex expressions in a list in python for labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, label

So I want to label an x-axis nicely with some tex symbols. I want to create a list like that

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

xticks = np.linspace(0, -14, 8)
labels = [ r'$\pi\!-\!10^{ x }$' for x in xticks ]

print(xticks, labels)
```

That is, the labels should be a list with the appropriate LaTex expressions with different the exponents from the np.array xticks. The problem is, the list `labels` contains not the values for `x` but only the symbol `x` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this could be turned into a one-liner but try

```
labels = []
for x in xticks:
    labels.append(r'$\pi\!-\!10^{{{}}}$'.format(x))
```

(Note the triple braces, annoying but necessary here)

Will give you something like

[image: Latex list]

Comment: Cheers, this works! Any idea why my code isn't working? Must have something to do with the the operation ´for ... in ...´ in python.

Comment: @schoeni You probably could rewrite that line `labels = [r’$\pi\!-\!10^{{{}}}$’.format(x) for x in xticks]` but I haven’t confirmed that

Comment: Yep, thanks man! I also changed the numpy array to a native python integer to get rid of `.0` in the exponents.